# Disable possibility to scan github organization in Jenkins github branch source plugin

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My team is providing Jenkins as a service to the developer teams. We would like to use the github branch source plugin to automatically build branches / PRs etc.
This plugin comes with a feature to scan the whole Github organization and create pipelines automatically for every repository.
But we don't want to allow developers to do this as we will have multiple Jenkins instances taking care of different repositories and accidentially building and deploying someone else's repository could have bad effects.

Is there a way to disable the "Github Organization" item type when creating a new item?

Things we have tried so far:

- Remove the plugin but then we don't get Github branch sources at all
- Restrict permissions, but you can only allow or disallow creating new jobs entirely
- Use the [extension-filter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+Filter+Plugin) but we couldn't find out what the correct values are. We tried `org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMNavigator$DescriptorImpl` as extension class and `hudson.model.AllView` as context without success.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I saw that there's an enterprise folder plugin from Cloudbees that allows you to restrict a folder to only certain project types, but we're not an enterprise customer.

Comment: I've found that renaming the branches it is monitoring (e.g. `master` to `disabled-master`) has effectively worked, but is not ideal.